# How to specify multiple ids for one record

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have `records` table with booking records info (8 columns). And I want to add to a record information about extra services that a client booked. I created `extra_services` table, but how can I specify multiple extra services to one record in `records` table?

If I add 9th column with just one id of extra service then there will be redundancy problem.

Comment: You need a link table, sometimes called a cross reference table `id_records_table, id_extraservice_table` and that it

Comment: you need another table for your extra services. make your id as primary key in first table

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little on what is the content of the extra_services table. If it does contain a set of extra services that can be booked you need a table to cross reference the bookings with the extra_services.
If on the other hand you are storing the booked extra services belonging to the record you can just use a ForeignKey field to the index of the records table in the extra_services table, that way you can track which records in extra_services belong the booking record.

Comment: `extra_services` table contains `id, name, price` columns. Did I understand correctly that I have to create new table where will be only 2 columns - id of extra service and id of record?